# Ошибка в верстке модуля bootstrap

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap

Написал модуль, но он не отображается, так как я где-то допустил ошибки.

Должны отображаться поля для ввода: Название проекта, Описание проекта, Водянистость, Сколько заказов может выполнить каждый копирайтер, Cтоп-слова, а также кнопка "Создать" (из кода все это видно, просто уточнил).

Код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Пример страницы</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="form-inline create_project" method="POST" action="">
            <input type="submit" class="create btn btn-default" name="create" value="Создать проект"/>
        </form>

        <div id="create_project" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Заголовок модального окна -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Создание проекта</h4>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Основное содержимое модального окна -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" placeholder="Название проекта">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text" placeholder="Описание проекта"></textarea>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" placeholder="Сколько заказов может выполнить каждый копирайтер" style="">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" placeholder="Водянистость" style="">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" placeholder="Cтоп-слова" style="">
                            </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Создать"/>
                                </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="scripts.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Код js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".create").click(function() {
        $("#create_project").modal('show');
    });
});
```

Код писал руководствуясь данным шаблоном: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target)

Comment: вы привели верстку страницы с модальным окном и говорите, что оно не появляется, резонный вопрос: где код, который это окно показывает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант: или уберите форму, повесив js-код на простую кнопку, или впишите после modal('show') тот же return false; чтобы форма не сабмитилась при нажатии.

Comment: Премного благодарен.
Воспользовался вторым вариантом, про суть которого совершенно забыл при попытках решения этой проблемы.